# Showing that convergence in $\mathcal{L}^1$ implies convergence in probability.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

I'm interested in hearing whether I can use the random variable $Y_n$ the way I do in the following proof.

Suppose that $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of integrable random variables, and that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_n - X|) = 0$. We will show that $X_n$ tends to $X$ in probability. To this end, let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary and define $Y_n = X_n - X$. Then, by Markov's inequality, we have that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n - X| \geq \epsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|Y_n| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(|Y_n|)}{\epsilon} \to 0, n \to \infty$, as $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|X_n - X|) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(|Y_n|) = 0$. Thus $X_n$ tends to $X$ in $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: This is fine, but your terminology is off - convergence in ${L}^1$ is usually used to denote convergence in mean - this is saying that the sequence converges in the ${L}^1$ metric space of random variables with the metric $d(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|]$. The notion you pursue is convergence in probability which is strictly weaker. Usually we just say that $X_n$ tends to $X$ in probability, or $X_n \overset{p}\to X.$ Your proof says that convergence in $L^1$ implies convergence in probability. As an exercise, try to show that the converse is not true.

Comment: You are showing that if $X_n - X = Y_n \to 0$ in $\mathscr{L}^1$ then $X_n - X \to 0$ in probability. The converse is well-known to be false. A typical example would construct a sequence $X_n$ such that $X_n$ is constant with large probability (say $X_n = 0$ woth probability $1-\frac{1}{n}$) and $X_n$ is large with the remainder probability (say $X_n = n$ with probability $1/n$). You choose these numbers so that $E(|X_n - X|)$ does not converge to zero (if you followed my example, $X = 0, X_n \geq 0$ and $E(X_n) = 1$) and therefore there is no $\mathscr{L}^1$ convergence.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Thanks for pointing this out: I intended the implication to be as was written in the proof, and not as I had written in the title.

Comment: Also, the final conclusion is incorrect (typo?) It should be "Thus $X_n$ tends to $X$ in probability".